# How can I perform a join/merge of a nested attribute across tables?

Tags: rethinkdb, reql

I have a table (db name is `libstats`, table name is `flowcells`) full of documents, all of which have a structure like this:

```
{
        "barcode": "C3W9UACXX",
        "id": "0021732f-2c42-4e9a-90fd-c68bb0d998dc",
        "libraries": [
            {
                "bases": 2431000000,
                "library_id": "SL58263",
                "perc_raw_clusters": 5.5,
                "pf_reads": 24312986,
                "q30": 92.23,
                "qscore": 35.82,
                "reads": 25834646,
                "lane": 1
             },...
         ]
}
```

The objects in the 'libraries' array will always have the keys shown. I need to add another key `library_name`.

I have another table `libraries` in another database `libraries` which has this `library_name` information. Here's an example document from that table:

```
{
   library_id: 'SL123456',
   library_name: 'my_library_name'
}
```

How can I use ReQL to accomplish this? I've gotten this far:

```
r.db('libstats').table('flowcells').merge(function(flowcell){
  return {'libraries': flowcell('libraries').map(function(library){
    return library.merge(
       {'library_name': 'foo'}
      )
  })
  }
}).limit(1)
```

which gives output in exactly the structure I want, but all of my attempts to acquire the `library_name` attribute using `getField`, `eqJoin()`, and `merge()` have thus far proved fruitless:

```
{
        "barcode": "C6841ANXX",
        "id": "007cae10-de3c-44df-9aee-1de9c88c1c21",
        "libraries": [
            {
                "bases": 194000000,
                "lane": "1",
                "library_id": "SL91807",
                "library_name": "foo",
                "perc_raw_clusters": 0.9,
                "pf_reads": 1942910,
                "q30": 96.55,
                "qscore": 36.06,
                "reads": 2045599
            },
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Naive Implementation**

You can do the following:

```
r.db('libstats').table('flowcells').merge(function(flowcell){
  return {'libraries': flowcell('libraries').map(function(library){
    return library.merge({ 
      // Query the `libraries` table
      'library_name': r.db('libraries').table('libraries')
        // Filter out certain elements
        .filter(function (row) {
          // Return all elements where the `library_id` is equal to 
          // the `library_id` in the `libstats` table
          return row('library_id').eq(library('library_id'))
        })
        // Return the `library_name` for the first element
        (0)('library_name')
    })
  })
  }
})
```

Keep in mind that you can also use a secondary index for this and make this a bit simpler and more performant.

**Better Solution**

If you have a lot of documents (10K+), you'll want to create an index on `library_id` and use the following query:

```
r.table('libstats').merge(function(flowcell){
  return {'libraries': flowcell('libraries').map(function(library){
    return library.merge({ 
      // Query the `libraries` table
      'library_name': r.table('libraries')
        // Filter out certain elements
      .getAll(library('library_id'), { index: 'library_id' })(0)('library_name')
    })
  })
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm slapping my forehead because I didn't think of that. Bravo!

Comment: Though I don't see any reason why this query shouldn't work, it times out after 300 seconds. I have an index set on `library_id` in the `libraries` table of the `libraries` DB. Any idea what I could be doing incorrectly?

Comment: I tested it out and it was working for me. What happens if you test it in the data explorer? Are you logging errors to make sure everything is working correctly? What happens if you start removing parts of the query and seeing when it works?

Comment: The Data Explorer was where I tested it and got the timeout error. The query works fine up until the filter part. For example, the query I show in my question works fine (and very quickly) I see exactly why the `filter()` function *should* work. The 'libraries' table has ~16K entries, but it's indexed on `library_id`. Not sure if the number of entries could be the reason for the delay.

Comment: Yes, the query was probably too slow (because it need to go through the table 10K+ times). I updated my answer. Keep in mind that indexes have to be used explicitly through `get`, `getAll`, or `between`.

Comment: Very nice. Newbie me keeps thinking there should be some magical direct way, but your updated solution makes perfect sense. Thanks so much for following up!

Comment: There's a GitHub issue for that if you want to weigh in: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/2356

Comment: its weird that you need to use round brackets in stead of square brackets to get the first element but okay it works thanks ;)

Comment: @webmaster Think if of it this way. You're not writiing, you're writing ReQL and ReQL turns the code you write into a TCP request  that it sends to the server. Hence, it doesn't ACTUALLY have the date it's manipulating at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version of a **NAIVE IMPLEMENTATION** in case someone has a similar problem:

```
r.db('libstats').table('flowcells').merge(function (flowcell) {
    return { libraries: flowcell("libraries").eqJoin("library_id", r.db("libraries").table("libraries") ).zip() };
})
```

(If there are other fields in libraries beside id and name, they will be joined, too)